# file manipulation with command line tools on linux

Tags: linux, command-line, awk, sed

I want to transform a file from this format

```
1;a;34;34;a
1;a;34;23;d
1;a;34;23;v
1;a;4;2;r
1;a;3;2;d
2;f;54;3;f
2;f;34;23;e
2;f;23;5;d
2;f;23;23;g
3;t;26;67;t
3;t;34;45;v
3;t;25;34;h
3;t;34;23;u
3;t;34;34;z
```

to this format

```
1;a;34;34;a;34;23;d;34;23;v;4;2;r;3;2;d
2;f;54;3;f;34;23;e;23;5;d;23;23;g;;;
3;t;26;67;t;34;45;v;25;34;h;34;23;u;34;34;z
```

These are cvs files, so it should work with awk or sed ... but I have failed till now. If the first value is the same, I want to add the last three values to the first line. And this will run till the last entry in the file.

Here some code in awk, but it does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{ FS = " *; *"} 
    { ORS = "\;" }    
    {
        x = $1
        print $0
    }
     { if (x == $1)
        print $3, $4, $5
       else
        print "\n"
    }
    END{
        print "\n"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
{ curr = $1 FS $2 }
curr == prev {
    sub(/^[^;]*;[^;]*/,"")
    printf "%s", $0
    next
}
{
    printf "%s%s", (NR>1?ORS:""), $0
    prev = curr
}
END { print "" }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1;a;34;34;a;34;23;d;34;23;v;4;2;r;3;2;d
2;f;54;3;f;34;23;e;23;5;d;23;23;g
3;t;26;67;t;34;45;v;25;34;h;34;23;u;34;34;z
```

Comment: This doesn´t work on awk version 20070501 -  what did I wrong?

Comment: I don't know what `awk version 20070501` means but the above will work with any modern awk. What OS are you on and whats the path to your awk command?

Comment: He is on a `mac` and I tested it and it worked as expected. @querendus Did you copy and paste the script correctly?

Comment: I use Max OS X 10.10.2 - all files are in the same directory: awk -f test.awk file > result

Comment: @querendus you did something wrong when you copy/pasted the script or you are doing something wrong in executing it. Please re-read my answer and make sure you follow it.

Comment: Worked with my ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly that you want to build a line from fields 3-5 of all lines with the same first two fields (preceded by those two fields), then

```
awk -F \; 'key != $1 FS $2 { if(NR != 1) print line; key = $1 FS $2; line = key } { line = line FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 } END { print line }' filename
```

That is

```
key != $1 FS $2 {                 # if the key (first two fields) changed
  if(NR != 1) print line;         # print the line (except at the very
                                  # beginning, to not get an empty line there)

  key = $1 FS $2                  # remember the new key
  line = key                      # and start building the next line
}
{
  line = line FS $3 FS $4 FS $5   # take the value fields from each line
}
END {                             # and at the very end,
  print line                      # print the last line (that the block above
}                                 # cannot handle)
```

Answer (score 1):

You got good answers in `awk`. Here is one in `perl`:

```
perl -F';' -lane'
    $key = join ";", @F[0..1];               # Establish your key
    $seen{$key}++ or push @rec, $key;        # Remember the order
    push @{ $h{$key} }, @F[2..$#F]           # Build your data structure
}{ 
    $, = ";";                                # Set the output list separator
    print $_, @{ $h{$_} } for @rec' file     # Print as per order
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to seem a lot more complicated than the other answers, but it's adding a few things:

- It computes the maximum number of fields from all built up lines
- Appends any missing fields as blanks to the end of the built up lines
- The posix awk on a mac doesn't maintain the order of array elements even when the keys are numbered when using the `for(key in array)` syntax.  To maintain the output order then, you can keep track of it as I've done or pipe to sort afterwards.

Having matching numbers of fields in the output appears to be a requirement per the specified output.  Without knowing what it should be, this awk script is built to load all the lines first, compute the maximum number of fields in an output line then output the lines with any adjustments in order.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"}

{
    key = $1
         # create an order array for the mac's version of awk
    if( key != last_key ) {
        order[++key_cnt] = key
        last_key = key
    }
    val = a[key]
        # build up an output line in array a for the given key
    start = (val=="" ? $1 OFS $2 : val)
    a[key] = start OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $5
        # count number of fields for each built up output line
    nf_a[key] += 3
}

END {
        # compute the max number of fields per any built up output line
    for(k in nf_a) {
        nf_max = (nf_a[k]>nf_max ? nf_a[k] : nf_max)
    }
    for(i=1; i<=key_cnt; i++) {
        key = order[i]
            # compute the number of blank flds necessary
        nf_pad = nf_max - nf_a[key]
        blank_flds = nf_pad!=0 ? sprintf( "%*s", nf_pad, OFS ) : ""
        gsub( / /, OFS, blank_flds )
            # output lines along with appended blank fields in order
        print a[key] blank_flds
    }
}
```

If the desired number of fields in the output lines is known ahead of time, simply appending the blank fields on key switch without all these arrays would work and make a simpler script.

I get the following output:

```
1;a;34;34;a;34;23;d;34;23;v;4;2;r;3;2;d
2;f;54;3;f;34;23;e;23;5;d;23;23;g;;;
3;t;26;67;t;34;45;v;25;34;h;34;23;u;34;34;z
```